# Multiple Functions in Javascript; 2nd function not working

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to make a button which shows more text on a webpage but my second function, textchange is not working. This function is working on my local html page but when uploaded to a already running website, the problem arises. I tried changing name of the function but assuming a function with same name exists somewhere across the platform but no good. Any idea what might be causing this?

```js
var collExt = document.getElementsByClassName("ButtnExt");
var btnExt = document.getElementById("PressExt");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < collExt.length; i++) {
  collExt[i].addEventListener("click", Opener);

  function Opener() {
    this.classList.toggle("activeExt");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
      collExt.value = "Close";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  btnExt.addEventListener("click", textchange);

  function textchange() {
    if (btnExt.textContent === "Read More") {
      btnExt.textContent = "Close Text";
    } else {
      btnExt.textContent = "Read More";
    }

  }
}
```

```css
.ButtnExt {
  background-color: rgb(197, 195, 195);
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.activeExt {
  border: none;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.exptextExt {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>Button Test</h1>

<p>
  Initial text
</p>
<button type="button" class="ButtnExt" id="PressExt">Read More</button>
<div class="exptextExt">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates amet alias, nihil aliquid dolorem quae impedit, reiciendis architecto porro laborum assumenda omnis. Quo magni at officia! Voluptates ex quaerat iste?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates amet alias, nihil aliquid dolorem quae impedit, reiciendis architecto porro laborum assumenda omnis. Quo magni at officia! Voluptates ex quaerat iste?
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates amet alias, nihil aliquid dolorem quae impedit, reiciendis architecto porro laborum assumenda omnis. Quo magni at officia! Voluptates ex quaerat iste?
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `class="ButtnExt" id="PressExt"` you are selecting the same button..... why are you doing `collExt` and `btnExt` pointing at same element with two event listeners?

Comment: *This function is working on my local html page* - and it is also working here, in the stack snippet.   So there's not really much we can do as, if it's not working for you (as I'm sure it's not) then there's something on your page where it's not working that you've not included here.   One possibility is that you have two/multiple buttons with the same ID

Comment: `the problem arises` can you describe the problem?  What is the reason for having `btnExt.addEventListener` within a loop?  The value of btnExt doesn’t change in that loop so you’d be adding multiple identical listeners to a single button.

Comment: @James The code does 2 things, expands the text and changes the button name to close text when clicked. Both functions work on my local server but on the website, the name of button doesn't change.

Comment: @epascarello My apologies, the code has gone through several revisions to make it work. This is the last version where I tried two different event listeners to try to make it work.

Comment: If you download the html page from the server and save it under another name, does it work locally or continue to not change the text?

Comment: Before going too much further, have you tried holding the shift key down while you reload the page from the server?  Try it - maybe you're working on a cached copy that is not up to date. . .

Comment: @James has highlighted a potential problem - if your `collExt.length` is *even* then your button will toggle twice - ie appear to do nothing.   Take the `btnExt.addEventListener` out of the loop and add some `console.log("..")` inside the event handlers so that you can see them fire/not fire.

Comment: Though I still think your issue is that you're using getElementById so it will *always* get the *first* button - though the snippet only has one, it's highly likely that you've looped the button (given the getElementsByClassName and the loop).  `<button type="button" class="ButtnExt" id="PressExt">Read More</button><button type="button" class="ButtnExt" id="PressExt">Read More</button>` - get by id will only find the first one.  Easily demonstrable by adding a 2nd para + expand in your snippet.

Comment: @freedomn-m that's a good point - `btnExt.addEventListener("click", textchange);`  (and the `textchange` function) should be moved outside the loop altogether.

Comment: @traktor I did download the HTML file and tried to run it from my local sever but it did not work. I don't know what I can interpret from that. 
And yeah, I use my webpage on incognito to see immediate changes and I did do the shift+ refresh but it did not work.

Comment: @freedomn-m, I did try taking out the function out of the loop and giving it console.log() and console.count() to see if the function is called. But function is not called at all. No response is seen in the console of the webpage.

Comment: If it's not calling it at all, then there's an issue with the getElementById, which is not demonstrated by the code in the question.  Can you update the snippet to *demonstrate* the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Try simplifying the code to make it conform to the design aims it needs to implement.

**Unique Id values**

Element `id` values must be unique in HTML, so only set `id` attributes on buttons that need their own particular styling or access from JavaScript.

**Supporting more that one button toggle**

The following code is aimed at aggressively simplifying the posted code  while also getting it to handle more than one button. It could be written differently, but only initializes buttons in a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler - so it won't work if placed in code that runs after the document loaded event has occurred (which may or may not be one of the problems you are facing).

**Code Snippet**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",  function() {

  var collExt = document.getElementsByClassName("ButtnExt");
  function Opener() {
    this.classList.toggle("activeExt");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("exptextExt"); // see note
    this.textContent  = this.classList.contains("activeExt")
      ? "close Text" : "Read More";
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < collExt.length; i++) {
    collExt[i].addEventListener("click", Opener);
  }

}, {once: true});
```

```css
.ButtnExt {
  background-color: rgb(197, 195, 195);
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.activeExt {
  border: none;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.exptextExt {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>Button Test</h1>

<p>
  Initial test
</p>
 <button type="button" class="ButtnExt">Read More</button>
 <div class="exptextExt">
   <p>
     Text to read for the first button goes here
 </div>

<p>
  Second button test
</p>
  <button type="button" class="ButtnExt">Read More</button>
  <div class="exptextExt">
    <p> Second button text goes here
</div>
```

**Note**

Be aware paragraph elements can't contain block level children and will self close (as if a `</p>` tag were encountered) when a block level element is encountered in HTML source. If you want to use toggle buttons at the end of a paragrah, try changing

```
this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("exptextExt");
```

to

```
(this.nextElementSibling || this.parentNode.nextElementSibling)
.toggle("exptextExt");
```